# Module found by manage.p but not by django-admin.py

Tags: python, django, settings, environment-variables, dreamhost

I am trying to get a django second site running on Dreamhost. I kept the set up almost exactly the same as my first site, which works, but I cannot get collect static to work. When I run `manage.py validate` it returns no errors but django-admin gives this

```
    ...
  File "/home/username/<virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings '<project>.settings.production' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named <project>.settings.production
```

I have set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `<project>.settings.production` and in the `passenger_wsgi.py` I have added the settings directory to the path.

I am using django 1.5.5. Could this be due to multiple sites?

**EDIT**
Collectstatic is not available under either of the 2 methods.

**EDIT** I just noticed that the `wsgi.py` has not been compiled. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Why do you have to use `django-admin`? Why don't you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Collectstatic doesn't show up as a command under either for some reason.

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yup, I have that part exactly the same as the site that is working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `<project>.settings.production`  what you need to add tou your `sys.path` is not the settings directory path but the path to `<project>`'s **parent** directory.

Comment: I have the parent in the path, I just tried putting the settings directory just in case.